# Image format changes while passed through express middleman

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, rest, express

I'm trying to use express to be the middleman between a server and a front-end application.

Images on the application have src links that typically looks like that:

```
<img src="http://localhost:3000/jira/rest/icon/icon.png?size=32" class="ruiAvatar__content" alt="">
```

My express server has a middleware to add a new header, then the request is redirected by an `app.get`:

```
app.use('/jira/rest', function (req, res, next) {
  req.headers['X-Atlassian-Token'] = 'no-check';

  next();
});

app.get('/jira/rest/*', (req, res) => {
  const url = 'http://localhost:2990' + req.url;

  axios
    .get(url, { headers: req.headers })
    .then((axiosResponse) => {
      const contentType = axiosResponse.headers['content-type'];
      const isImage =
        contentType && axiosResponse.headers['content-type'].includes('image/');

      if (isImage) {
        res.send(JSON.stringify(axiosResponse.data));
  } else res.send(JSON.stringify(axiosResponse.data));
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.log('err', error);
  res.send(JSON.stringify(error));
});  });
```

I'm receiving back a string, but the web browser is not able to display it (I have the red square instead), but I see a 200 response status for my rest call.

The strings looks like that:

```
�PNG\r\n\u001a\n\u0000\u0000\u0000\rIHDR\u0000\u0000\u00000\u0000\u0000\u00000\b\u0006\u0000\u0000\u0000W\u0002��\u0000\u0000\u0000�IDATx���\r�0\u0014��\b\u0007�\u0010:A1���\rG\u001d�\u0019��8\n��\u0005�Oo��� i��%�@�4�\u0017B\u0002\b\u0001\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000�\u000ed�:X��h��h����؍\u001d����k�ѥ&\u001e\u0019Ǯa�5C\u0006�ϻ�]�\u0000�0�\u0012����%�)'����l�\u001f\u0001\b@\u0000\u0002\u0010���\u0002�.��R\u0002>=L�M\u0019\u0001�U<��k�7�F��k��y��ٿ\u000e�3\n\b?�eg�\\\u0002�5\bh����� ��k���NQ%;�[ESr\u0001މ��\u0011?�\u0001\u0000\u0000�\rwy�\u0006bV\u0010E�\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000IEND�B`�
```

I can't tell what format this is from my personal knowledge and from half a day of googling it.
Neither can I tell if I should modify it to pass it to my application in a readable format.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Content looks like a PNG (the magic characters at the front indicate as much). Seems like you're sending the wrong `content-type` (`image/jpeg` instead of `image/png`).

Comment: My mistake, I left a test code in my snippet. I tested two cases one where I stringify, one where I don't. Same result though the image doesn't show.

Answer (score 0):

If your intent is for the front-end code to display the response as an image, you'll want to send an image response:

```
if (isImage) {
  res
    .set('content-type', axiosResponse.headers['content-type'])
    .send(axiosResponse.data);
} else {
  // ...
}
```

Since you've been converting the binary content you're getting from axios into a JSON string, and because you're not setting the `content-type`, your response is not what a browser expects for an image.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I had tried setting the content-type to whatever the axiosResponse content-type is before, then sent the raw data. Without success. 
I tried with your code to be safe and I still get an image block without image. The preview in the network tab is empty as well.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer by changing my strategy.

At the begginning of my route, I check if the request header accept images, then I redirect if necessary:

```
app.get('/jira/rest/*', (req, res) => {
  const url = 'http://localhost:2990' + req.url;
  const isImage = req.headers.accept.includes('image');

  if (isImage) return res.redirect(url);

  axios
    .get(url, { headers: req.headers })
    .then((axiosResponse) => {
      const contentType = axiosResponse.headers['content-type'];

      res.set('content-type', contentType);
      res.send(JSON.stringify(axiosResponse.data));
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      res
        .status(error.response.status)
        .send(JSON.stringify(error.response.data.errors));
    });
});
```